# Why is a transistor required when connecting relays to an Arduino?

Tags: arduino, transistors, relay

I am trying to use a simple Arduino circuit to turn an AC lamp on and off. This is the circuit I was about to try which I got from [a website](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-relay-control#comment-form).

[image]

I don't understand why a transistor is required there. I thought we already have a 5 V output which we can directly connect to the relay.

Comment: But I have already got some best answers I think .. Thanks

Comment: More solutions than you ever wanted here: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/blog/relay-switch-circuit.html - 
Scroll down to "Logic Controlled Relay Switch Circuit" - N-channel enhancement-MOSFET would be my personal preference.

Comment: @EdRandall Thanks a lot for that... Those are really informative for me such beginners..

Comment: This is a super FAQ. Why are such questions not immediately closed as a duplicate? Why do we need to answer the same questions over and over again?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Sounds like a question for meta.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The average microcontroller like on your Arduino has only limited ‘strength’ on the port pins. Typically it might be 2..20mA. Your relay might require 60mA at a guess so you require some means of amplifying the port pin. A transistor or mosfet is commonly used.

Note your diagram is missing a resistor in series with the transistor as the transistor only requires around 0.7V to turn it on. The resistor drops the port pin voltage from 5V down to 0.7V.

Comment: THanks a lot.. But I didnt follow the resistor part... :( Please suggest the value if you dont mind . So its in series to the base?? Aruduino Pin -> Resistor -> Transistor Base, is it correct friend??

Comment: There’s tutorials a plenty out there as what you ask is super common. At a guess I’d make the resistor 1K. The tutorials should cover how you can calculate tge resistance required.

Comment: A resistor may as well not be needed, if the pin has an internal pullup.

Comment: The resistor is needed to limit the base current in the transistor. Otherwise you'll risk damage to the gpio port. It's really more of a current issue than a voltage one (but the ohm law exists…)

Comment: fraxinus you are mistaking the *input* pullup resistor with the *output* current limiting resistor.

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio, you need to use the `@username` syntax if you want fraxinus to receive a ping in his/her inbox.

Comment: It might be nice to include a small schematic showing the "missing" resistor, or state the the resistor goes to the base of the transistor from the Arduino output pin. Arduino users aren't the most proficient of electrical engineers and they may not immediately understand.

Comment: Yeah the phrasing "in series with" is confusing when you're talking about a 3-terminal device.  You mean a resistor on the base - not on the collector.

Comment: 2-20 mA... I've used a microcontroller with outputs that can't even drive more than a few hundred μA!

Comment: @Hearth micropower MCUs or high powered almost-CPU often have weak outputs. The old 6502 (NMOS IIRC) even needed buffers to go to its own bus! The AVR and the baseline PICs seems to be the last ones to have such heavy drive on *all* the GPIO

Comment: "A transistor or mosfet..." MOSFET is a type of transistor too. What you mean is BJT.

Comment: @Durnus. The Fairchild datasheet refers to the BC547 as a transistor.

Comment: @Kartman I don't know when the BC547 was first made available, but I wouldn't be surprised if it was back before MOSFETs were common. Even if not, calling it a transistor is hardly wrong. That said, I don't think it's correct to use "transistor" to mean specifically "BJT" as opposed to other types of transistor. MOSFETs are also transistors, as are JFETs and HEMTs, and even point-contact transistors and UJTs, not that those are ever used anymore.

Comment: @Kartman Yes, the "T" in BJT means "transistor".  The "T" in MOSFET **also** means "transistor".  As does the "T" in JFET and the "T" in HEMT and the "T" in IGBT, etc...

Comment: Come on guys, we’re splitting hairs here. It is not adding value to the question.

Comment: @Kartman It's not splitting hairs - this answer will be here for a long time, and so long as it contains the phrase *"transistor or mosfet"* it continues to contain an inaccuracy that can add confusion to learners of electronics who will read this and walk away with the idea that transistors and mosfets are different types of thing, which they are not.  It's like saying you can create music with a musical instrument **or** a piano.  Or that trees can produce fruits *or* apples; that you can get to work using a vehicle *or* a car, etc.

Comment: @J... how about ‘LCD display’ and ‘ATM machine’?

Comment: @Kartman Those are completely [unrelated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAS_syndrome).  It would apply here if you said "A mosfet transistor", but the phrasing in question is "a transistor *or* mosfet".  These are logically different.

Comment: J... I think we can safely say that the participants of this discussion all know the difference between a BJT and a MOSFET. Yes, referring to a BJT as a 'transistor' is imprecise but in the context of the original question there was no ambiguity. I even tried to introduce some humour by referring to the Fairchild datasheet. The imprecision was noted and I motioned to stop any further unproductive discussion. Seems you ignored the stop sign and wanted to hammer the nail a bit more. There is no argument from me so please stop. Edit my answer if that will help you. It ends here.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, here's (almost) everything you need:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsF2bR.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The Arduino uses an ATMEGA MCU (most of the AVRs have similar specs so it's not critical) so the datasheet has the relevant informations:

- At 5V supply the output port HIGH voltage is *at least* 4.2V, with 20mA load
- Still a 5V, the output port LOW voltage is *at most* 0.7V, with 20mA load

Since they quote the current at 20mA it's safe to assume that the current is available (up to 400mA *total* for the chip, as in the absolute maximums).

From the BC547 datasheet you can see that:

- Maximum current capability is 100mA (the size of your relay coil)
- DC current gain (hFE) at 2mA is *at least* 110
- Base emitter saturation is typically 0.7V
- Base emitter on voltage *could* go low at 0.55V (this is a beginner's trap)

Now, for the calculations: you want to put some mA in the base with the GPIO high: so you have a 4.2V source, the base resistore and the B-E junction (which is substantially a diode for this purpose, and drops 0.7V)

You then leave with at lease 3.5V on the resistor to drop. The proposed 1k resistor limits the current to about 3.5mA (minimum). That, multiplied by the hFA gives a potential 350mA of collector current which is enough (as in, if you try to pull more than 100mA the BJT dies). So even a slightly larger resistor will work (not too much however)

Now, for the above mentioned trap: if you are *really* unlucky you could have an AVR with a very high low output (0.7V) and a BJT with a very low VBE (0.55V). So the relay could actually trigger when the GPIO is low!

For that reason it's useful to add another resistor between base and emitter to shunt the excess current. The calculation is not immediate (think a resistor in parallel to the B-E junction diode). However a 10k resistor is useful and traditional for many decades.

Comment: Good answer, I'd just add that in rugged designs, the base should also have a pull resistor so that the BJT is in a defined state when the MCU is starting up or resetting. The shunt resistor you mention would act as such.

Comment: For MOSFETs it's quite important since they have an high impedance gate and a tristated output is essentially random; a BJT doesn't suffer from that issue: no base current, no collector current. However the VBE is usually lower that the VGSth so this other problem is typical

Comment: @LorenzoMarcantonio Thats really an excellent answer man.. Thanks a lot

Comment: Yeah but you can't really rely on the MCU having some well-defined state during reset or power up. Could be some threestate, could be floating, could be input... yeah it's unlikely that something from the MCU side would actually drive the pin high as needed for NPN, but there's also EMI.

Comment: +1 - for including the schematic - This *should* be the accepted answer..!

Comment: Are you assuming the 5 volts is also coming from the Arduino as well? Or would the pin not be enough? If the coil is only sourcing 20 mA, then it should work, right?

Comment: the +5 supply is from the power rail. If the coil *sinks* 20mA there should no issue. By the way the 547 IIRC has something like 40-60 VCEmax so even a 12V relay would work in the same way (*nothing* change for base bias)

Answer (score 6):

Let me try to simplify:

- A - Check the minimum current needed to turn ON the relay in datasheet.
- B - Check the maximum current the MCU GPIO can source in the datasheet

If B>A then you don't need a transistor, otherwise to source extra current required by the relay you need transistor.

Answer (score 3):

There are relays which don't need a transistor to be operated: for instance the HE3300 reed relays need as little as 10 mA and can be driven directly by a microcontroller pin. Note that such relays are in turn rather limited w.r.t the power their contacts can switch (for HE3300 that would be 10W max).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to limited current capacities of outputs: Sinking significant current, even within specification, will create more heating of the microcontroller (not good for reliability); also, there might be a limit to total output (sink) current for the whole microcontroller, limiting the amount of relays that can be directly controlled by it.

Also, driving significant current spikes through the ground connection of the MCU can potentially create signal integrity problems (forcing a bus ground in a place where it might not be desirable), especially if the MCU has some analog I/O and no separate AGND.

Also, relays and motors are considered devices that create back EMF spikes and other effects which, while you have to mitigate them with devices like freewheeling diodes and/or snubbers in any case, you want to keep somewhat isolated from a sensitive LSI part like a MCU.